# LaTeX graphic[sx] package with eplain fails with driver dvipdfmx

Tags: graphics, plain-tex, eplain

According to [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-dvipdfmgraphics), in order to get bounding box support (with `.xbb` and `.bb` files) with dvipdfm[x] and non-eps graphics files, one must specify the driver as in:

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```

Unfortunately this fails with

```
Forbidden control sequence found while scanning...\newif...
```

I believe that this is caused by plainTeX's definition of \newif to be "outer".

So a few questions:

1. Could this be considered a bug in `miniltx` / eplain?
2. What is the advantage in a package like `graphic[sx]` in using `\newif` in an "inner" way?  In other words, is it worth breaking plainTeX to make it usable in an "inner" way?
3. What is the least invasive/easiest way to resolve?

For answer to #3, I can only think of doing the following:

```
% Save the plain format's \newif
\let\plainnewif = \newif

% Re-def \newif without \outer
\catcode`@ = 11
\def\newif#1{\count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \def\@if#1{true}{\let#1=\iftrue}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \def\@if#1{false}{\let#1=\iffalse}%
  \@if#1{false}\escapechar\count@}
\catcode`@ = 12

% latex packages (assumes the use of eplain)
\beginpackages
    \usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\endpackages

% Restore plain format's \newif
\let\newif = \plainnewif
```

Answer (score 3):

I an not able to reconstruct the error. But for de-outerisation of an outer macro you can write a more simple code:

```
\let\plainnewif=\newif
\def\newif{\csname plainnewif\endcsname}
```

Comment: I can get the error with a simple demo: `\pdfoutput=0 \input eplain \beginpackages\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}\endpackages` and TeX Live 2014 updated today.

Comment: Thanks for showing an easier way how to "de-outerize".  Can you explain why it works though?

Answer (score 3):

Tackling the 'where is the issue' part specifically,  I can find one use of `\newif` in `dvipdfmx.def`:

```
\def\Ginclude@eps#1{%
 \message{<#1>}%
  \bgroup
  \newif\if@trim@vport
  \ifx\Undefined\Gin@vllx\else\@trim@vporttrue\fi
  \def\@tempa{!}%
  \dimen@\Gin@urx\p@
  \advance\dimen@ -\Gin@llx\p@
  \if@trim@vport
  \advance\dimen@ \Gin@vllx\p@
  \fi
  \edef\Gin@urx{\strip@pt\dimen@}%
  \dimen@\Gin@ury\p@
  \advance\dimen@ -\Gin@lly\p@
  \if@trim@vport
  \advance\dimen@ \Gin@vlly\p@
  \fi
  \edef\Gin@ury{\strip@pt\dimen@}%
  \dimen@\Gin@req@width
  \dimen@ii.1bp%
  \divide\dimen@\dimen@ii
  \@tempdima\Gin@req@height
  \divide\@tempdima\dimen@ii
    \special{PSfile="#1"\space
      \if@trim@vport
      llx=\Gin@vllx\space
      lly=\Gin@vlly\space
      \fi
      urx=\Gin@urx\space
      ury=\Gin@ury\space
      \ifx\Gin@scalex\@tempa\else rwi=\number\dimen@\space\fi
      \ifx\Gin@scaley\@tempa\else rhi=\number\@tempdima\space\fi
      \ifGin@clip clip\fi}%
  \egroup}
```

Looking at that code, I think an alternative with the conditional moved outside of the macro should also work

```
\newif\if@trim@vport
\def\Ginclude@eps#1{%
 \message{<#1>}%
  \bgroup
  \@trim@vportfalse
  \ifx\Undefined\Gin@vllx\else\@trim@vporttrue\fi
  \def\@tempa{!}%
  \dimen@\Gin@urx\p@
  \advance\dimen@ -\Gin@llx\p@
  \if@trim@vport
  \advance\dimen@ \Gin@vllx\p@
  \fi
  \edef\Gin@urx{\strip@pt\dimen@}%
  \dimen@\Gin@ury\p@
  \advance\dimen@ -\Gin@lly\p@
  \if@trim@vport
  \advance\dimen@ \Gin@vlly\p@
  \fi
  \edef\Gin@ury{\strip@pt\dimen@}%
  \dimen@\Gin@req@width
  \dimen@ii.1bp%
  \divide\dimen@\dimen@ii
  \@tempdima\Gin@req@height
  \divide\@tempdima\dimen@ii
    \special{PSfile="#1"\space
      \if@trim@vport
      llx=\Gin@vllx\space
      lly=\Gin@vlly\space
      \fi
      urx=\Gin@urx\space
      ury=\Gin@ury\space
      \ifx\Gin@scalex\@tempa\else rwi=\number\dimen@\space\fi
      \ifx\Gin@scaley\@tempa\else rhi=\number\@tempdima\space\fi
      \ifGin@clip clip\fi}%
  \egroup}
```

Indeed, I suspect that this is one place where plain's `\outer` definition of `\newif` is pointing up an oddity: there's no obvious reason why the current code has the definition where it does.

Note that this is not really a bug in `miniltx`: it's usually understood that code that works with plain (even if LaTeX-derived) has to allow for an `\outer`  version of `\newif` (either by not using it in macros or by accessing by csname).

Comment: I should be able to arrange a fix here: I'll wait and see if I've missed some reason for the current approach.

Comment: I can't see any reason to have a local `\newif` there

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  Also, I think it is actually very helpful to understand the relationship between LaTeX derived but plainTeX supported code.